# River city - a city with a river running through it?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning, prepositional-objects

On Wikipedia there is a page called River city and there is a list of cities located **on a river**:

> Australia: 
> Brisbane, Queensland

> China: 
> Jilin City 
> Wuhan

> New Zealand: 
> Whanganui

> United States:    
> Cape Girardeau, Missouri 
> Chattanooga, Tennessee
> Danville, Virginia 
> Decatur, Alabama 
> Evansville, Indiana 
> Grand Rapids, Michigan 
> Huntington, West Virginia 
> Jacksonville, Florida 
> Lawrence, Kansas 
> Missoula, Montana 
> Richmond, Virginia 
> Sacramento, California 
> San Antonio, Texas 
> St. Louis, Missouri 
> Louisville, Kentucky

> 

Does this mean there is a river running through the city? What exactly does it mean to be “on a river”?

Comment: Yes. I read in a book that Reading, Pennsylvania is a city on the Schuykill River as well.

Comment: A city on a river [meaning: beside a river] can be called a river city. A city with a river running through it cannot. The Seine runs through Paris, the Thames runs through London: these are not river cities.

Comment: That page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_city shows that list as cities with "River city" as a nickname.

Answer (score 1):

*Clarification: as far as I know, "River City" is not an established, *generic* phrase, but more likely a nickname that each of these has adopted as a proper noun.*

Sure, a city "on" a river might have the river running "through" it, or merely alongside. Since rivers make easy natural transportation routes, cities have often sprung up on their banks. If there is no natural geographical obstacle to it, they might often spill onto the opposite bank as well (London, Paris). In some cases that might be impractical, but a city can be "on" a river by being only "on" one side of it, just as it might be "on" a bay or "on" the ocean.

Comment: Ok but if the city is next to an ocean and a river feeds into it, would the city be on the ocean or on a river?

Comment: @meepyer Both can be true at once.

Comment: Ok now that I’ve dug deeper I see now that some of the cities on the list above have a river running through them, like Jacksonville in Florida.

Comment: Britain has a number of towns and cities built at the mouth of a river (where it flows into the sea) - Plymouth, Yarmouth, Dartmouth etc.

Comment: @KateBunting ... as well as a number of place names incorporating "on," like Stratford-upon-Avon, with parallels in other languages (e.g. a number of German towns "-am Rhein")

Comment: And quite a few "-sur-Mer"s in France.